# Netezza SQL - Auto incrementing column duplicate

Tags: sql, netezza

Rookie with Netezza SQL so need some guidance.

I have a table TABLE_A in Netezza with 3 columns:

1. Name
2. Account_No
3. Month

TABLE_A gets updated every month with new data. The column Account_No however is a character column with numeric data. I want to update TABLE_A such that I can have a integer format column of Account_No along with the character column and whenever data is updated, the integer column should also get automatically updated as well. So my TABLE_A will look something like this:

1. Name
2. Account_No
3. Month
4. Account_No_INT

The column Account_No never starts with 0. Thank you.

Comment: Phone "numbers" however are not numbers - what happens with a number that begins 0 or 00...?  What purpose would such a column serve, it makes no sense to perform any integer operation on a phone number...?

Comment: So this column is just a 10 digit numeric column. It will never begin with 0 or 00 in my case

Comment: That's the case now, but will it always be? In my region for example many years ago area codes were 4-digits, then were changed to be 5 digits with existing codes prefixed with zero. Anyway, the feature you need is a *computed column* which I don't believe is supported - you could however use a *View*

Comment: Yes. It will be, I apologize for the confusion. I am only dealing with a character column which has 10 numeric digits. I need a duplicate with integer format. I have edited my question to change it from Phone_Number to Account_No. The Account_No never starts with 0.